# How can I create UI with arrow react native?

Tags: react-native, mobile, view, uiview

I want to create a UI like the picture below.

[image]

How can I implement it? Anyone have an idea for this. Pls help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. you can design that arrow with position: 'absolute' css property. 
try to implement below code!

```
     <View style={{ marginTop: 10, marginHorizontal: 15 }}>
      <View style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
        <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#e5f8ff', borderColor: '#007299'  }}>
          <Text>Top Note</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 9, left: -5 }}>
          <View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 1, borderLeftWidth: 1 ,backgroundColor: '#e5f8ff', borderColor: '#007299', width: 10, height: 10, transform: [{ rotate: '45deg'}] }}>

          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
```

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juCeV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working [Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@karthik.01/ranting-cashew)

As also @pds answer suggest you need to make the arrow component as absolute to position it over the message body.

Using CSS triangle and absolute positioning you can get the working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some libraries which will help you to achieve your whole UI :

- triangle : https://github.com/Jpoliachik/react-native-triangle

[image]

- timeline-listview : https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-timeline-listview
  [image]
- timeline-theme : https://github.com/tomzaku/react-native-timeline-theme
  [image]